# Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}e^{-k}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing an exercise about the convergence of series:

> Is
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}e^{-k}$$ 
>   convergent?

The following limit is given:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k!}{\sqrt{2\pi k}(k/e)^k}=1.
$$

Ratio test which would give the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}x^k$ doesn't work here. I don't see how I can use the known limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in your limit into the general term will tell you that the general term is of order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}.$ Since the terms are positive, the series diverges (say, by integral test, or comparison test).

To elaborate. turning your limit upside down, gives you

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2\pi k}\frac{ (k/e)^k}{k!} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{2\pi k} \frac{k^k}{e^k k!} = 1.$$

The term just before the rightmost equality looks like the term in your sum, except you have  an extra $\sqrt{2\pi k}$ term. So, your general term is of order of

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi k}},$$ so your series diverges, by comparison with the harmonic series $\sum\frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: This is known as limit comparison test.

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit more? I don't see how it works.

Comment: @HansEngler I have long ago given up on the $n^2$ version of the limit test taxonomies...

Comment: @Igor - I assume this comes from a Calculus II course where this taxonomy is often used. :)

Comment: @Jack - Are you familiar with the limit comparison test?

Comment: @HansEngler, Thank you for pointing out the "LCT". I didn't learn it before.